# How to assign an `user_id` to a newly created record in Laravel's Lighthouse?

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

Laravel's Lighthouse has directives to perform data-modifying CRUD operations directly on the database: `@create`, `@delete`, and `@update`.

A simple CRUD's create can be implemented like this:

```
type Mutation {
  createPost(title: String!): Post @create
}
```

This works, but it creates records without an owner. My question is: **How to assign an `user_id` to a newly created record?**

I mean, without having to use a resolver.

I could add an `user_id` parameter, like this:

```
type Mutation {
  createPost(user_id: ID, title: String!): Post @create
}
```

But that would cause a huge security issue - anyone could add or change records of other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@inject`](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#inject) directive, like `@inject(context: "user.id", name: "user_id")`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use an observer on your model and save the user_id there with `auth()->id();`